# Why is -like not working but -match does?

Tags: powershell

I got this script from here and it work for uninstalling an application, but only when `-match` is used instead of `-like` in the first 2 lines, even when I use the entire app name.

The app's name includes the version, so I'd like to wildcard the name in the script to support "MyApp 2.4.1", etc. Thanks!

```
$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | 
     foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -like "MyApp*" } | select UninstallString

$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | 
     foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -like "MyApp*" } | select UninstallString

if ($uninstall64) {
   $uninstall64 = $uninstall64.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
   $uninstall64 = $uninstall64.Trim()

   Write "Uninstalling..."
   start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall64 /qb" -Wait
}

if ($uninstall32) {
   $uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
   $uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()

   Write "Uninstalling..."
   start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall32 /qb" -Wait
}
```

Comment: If `-match` worked but `-like` did not the only difference is that if the actual string Was "1MyAPP 2.3.4" or " MyAPP 2.3.4" `-match` would find it since match only cares if the string is present anywhere but like would not since it expects the first character to be M and so on. Wonder if there are any characters before M. If you changed the clause to `?{ $_ -match "^MyApp" }` does it still work?

Comment: I think you're right. I don't see any leading characters in the name property, but I added a `*` to the beginning as well and it worked. Feel free to submit as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following string " MyApp 2.3.4" while will look at the important difference between the two examples you refer to:

- Like `? { $_ -like "MyApp*" }`
- Match `? { $_ -match "MyApp*" }`

`-Like` is looking for a string *starting* with "MyApp" followed by anything. `-Match` is looking for the text "MyApp" followed by any character. The `-Like` would fail since there is a preceding space. `-Match` treats "MyApp*" as a regex string which looks for "MyApp" followed by any character. In this case it cares not about the space to it matches. I suspect the `-match` would fail if you changed it too `? { $_ -match "^MyApp*" }` as the caret says start of string.

If you want `-like` to work in this case you should change it to  `? { $_ -like "*MyApp*" }`

**Important**

While I am correct about why your comparison was not working [Ansgar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27973812/3829407) addresses the reason this issue was happening to you in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

`Get-ItemProperty` produces an object, not a string. Check the `DisplayName` property instead of the object itself. You should also expand the uninstall string, so you don't need to use `$uninstall64.UninstallString` later.

```
$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | 
                 foreach { gp $_.PSPath } |
                 ? { $_.DisplayName -like "MyApp*" } |
                 select -Expand UninstallString
```

Comment: crap... that is the reason he is having issues with `-like` and `-match`. The entire string that represents a registry item is being compared. "MyApp" appears somewhere in the middle. I am right about why it was not working however this addresses the core issue. I love SO